# Is MatIterator_ less efficient than raw pointers in any meaningful way?

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, iterator

While reading the scan images tutorial, I they describe [The iterator (safe) method](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-iterator-safe-method) and then there is [The efficient way](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way).

But from my experience with `std::vector`, for example, iterators and raw pointers are basically the same in terms of speed - I doubt that the generated assembly/executable code is even different in a Release build. Isn't that true for cv::Mat as well? Because the way it's phrased in the tutorial, they imply that MatIterator_ is safer, but slower.

Also, if it is slower, how much slower is it, percentage-wise? Is it slower in a meaningful way, like 10% slower, or more like 0.1% slower?

**Note:** I'm talking about a Release build, with all optimizations turned on. In a Debug build the iterator is likely to have asserts and what-not.

Comment: Why not try profiling?

Answer (score 0):

I found a performance comparison [at the end of the same tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#performance-difference), so I'll post here the results:

> Performance Difference
>
> For the best result compile the program and run it on your own speed. For showing off better the differences I’ve used a quite large (2560 X 1600) image. The performance presented here are for color images. For a more accurate value I’ve averaged the value I got from the call of the function for hundred times.
>
> Efficient Way 79.4717 milliseconds
> Iterator  83.7201 milliseconds
> On-The-Fly RA 93.7878 milliseconds
> LUT function  32.5759 milliseconds
>
> We can conclude a couple of things. If possible, use the already made
> functions of OpenCV (instead reinventing these). The fastest method
> turns out to be the LUT function. This is because the OpenCV library
> is multi-thread enabled via Intel Threaded Building Blocks. However,
> if you need to write a simple image scan prefer the pointer method.
> The iterator is a safer bet, however quite slower. Using the
> on-the-fly reference access method for full image scan is the most
> costly in debug mode. In the release mode it may beat the iterator
> approach or not, however it surely sacrifices for this the safety
> trait of iterators.

So that means that the iterator method is 5% slower than raw pointers in these performance tests.